# Converting Object to JSON String For POST Request

Tags: json, swift, post, ios8, swifty-json

I have an object that is an instance of a class similar to this:

```
class MyClass {
    let aString: String
    let bString: String
    var cArray = [AnotherClass]()

    init etc...
}
```

AnotherClass is something like:

```
class AnotherClass {
    let aInt: Int
    let bInt: Int
    var cFloat = Float

    init etc...
}
```

Ok, now i need to pass that object (instance of MyClass) as a POST request *string* parameter with the following format:

```
 {
     "aString": "1",
     "bString": "yannis",
     "cArray": [
       {
         "aInt": 1965887,
         "bInt": 36513032311523,
         "cFloat": 1.0
       },
       {
         "aInt": 1916915,
         "bInt": 360397932121597,
         "cFloat": 1.0
       }
     ]
 }
```

Any ideas how to achieve this? I'm using Swift 1.2 (and SwiftyJSON, if that helps)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to convert both objects into Dictionaries by adding a function like:

```
func convertToDictionary() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

    return [
        "aString": self.aString,
        "bString": self.bString,
        "cArray": self.cArray
    ]
}
```

to both classes.

Then serialize it using:

```
let theJSONData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(
  dictionary ,
  options: NSJSONWritingOptions(0),
  error: nil)
```

Where `dictionary` is something like `dictionary =  myClass.convertToDictionary`

Maybe even serialize the nested objects in the Array for `MyClass` before serializing the `MyClass` object as well.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as far I know [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) not support *Object Mapping to JSON*, it's only for parse JSON object retrieved from some source.

If you need to make *Object Mapping to JSON* there are some nice libraries you can use like the two following :

- [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper)
- [swift-serializer](https://github.com/Mailcloud/swift-serializer)

The documentation of both are very easy to follow. But if you don't need to create a very complex JSON from a very complex class, you can handle it yourself with some method to map your object to JSON and with the help of the class [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html) you can validate your creation before use it. You can learn a lot from make the mapping yourself in the [Strong Type Object Serialization to JSON (Nerd Alert)](http://blog.mailcloud.com/technology/apple-swift-code-strong-type-object-serialization-to-json/) article.

I hope this help you.